# java.lang.ClassCastException while adding HeaderView to List

Tags: android, android-listview, header, classcastexception, android-framelayout

I am getting following exception while adding header to listview on the line         `channellist.addHeaderView(header);`-

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

I have  tried both-

```
View header = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.headerchannel, null);
```

and

```
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.headerchannel, null,false);
```

but same exception I am getting.
My HomeActivity do have a framelayout and it is required for my project.

Answer (score 1):

if u see:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

u must do this:

```
header.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

before
`channellist.addHeaderView(header);`

Comment: then try change in header.xml RelativeLayout to FrameLayout

Comment: have u listview and header in one xml?  why u used android:layout_below="@+id/header"

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.headerchannel, null);
```

Comment: @BhuvneshVarma oh, can you try this `View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.headerchannel, channellist, false);`?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your header your root element is `RelativeLayout`. Which is `ViewGroup` not View. So Inflate it in a `ViewGroup`.

That's the reason it gives you ClassCastException. You are trying to convert ViewGroup intp View.

So first of all check that your layout is ViewGroup or View.
If it's viewgroup you have to do this ..

```
ViewGroup header = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.headerchannel, null);
```

Or it's just a view then..

```
View header = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.headerchannel, null);
```

Comment: have you tried ViewGroup or LayoutInflater.from()..?

Comment: remove false parameter from this line `View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.headerchannel, null,false);`  like this `View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.headerchannel, null);` and try